# Is there a plugin for easly accessing Google Bookmarks from Firefox 7?

Tags: google-bookmarks, firefox-extensions

I used to use a plugin (Gmarks) that integrated FF and Google bookmarks.

However, it's not compatible with FF 8.

Can anyone suggest an easy to use alternative that works with Firefox 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) to sync bookmarks across browsers for a long time now. It works very well.

Comment: Xmarks works great for keep synchronized the bookmarks between different browsers and machines.

Comment: Another vote for Xmarks. :)